# Find values of $x$ that verify the inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I have to find the values of $x$ that verify the inequality $\operatorname{arcsin}(\frac 1x)-\operatorname{arccos}(\frac 1x) \geq0$.

Let $f(x) = \operatorname{arcsin}(\frac 1x) - \operatorname{arccos}(\frac 1x).$

I differentiated $f(x)$ and I get that $f'(x)= \frac {-2}{\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}$,  so $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing over $\mathbb{R}$, right? But:

$\operatorname{arcsin}(x):[-1,1]\to[-\frac \pi2,\frac\pi2]$ and $\operatorname{arccos}(x):[-1,1]\to[0,\pi]$.

Does this affect my inequality and, if so, how?

Comment: Minor note: the word you want is 'satisfy', not 'verify'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First consider $\arcsin(x)-\arccos(x)\ge0$.

For $\displaystyle x\in\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1\right]$, $\displaystyle \arcsin(x)\ge\frac{\pi}{4}\ge \arccos(x)$

For $\displaystyle x\in\left[-1,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$, $\displaystyle \arcsin(x)<\frac{\pi}{4}< \arccos(x)$

So, $\displaystyle \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\arccos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\ge0$ if and only if $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\le \frac{1}{x}\le 1$, i.e., $$1\le x\le \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: If I were to define a function as $f(x) = arcsin(x) - arccos(x)$ on what domain would it be defined? and would that affect my inequality, studying that function? and would it work if I just defined $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The domain is $[-1,1]$. Numbers outside this range cannot be sine or cosine of any angle.

Comment: You can use desmos to plot the graph. It helps us to visualize the problem.

Comment: and for $arcsin(\frac 1x) - arccos(\frac 1x)$?

Comment: $(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)$

Comment: and how did you get there?

Comment: $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$ have the same domain. We don't have to worry about the fact that their ranges are different.

Comment: $\sin:[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]\to[-1,1]$ is a strictly increasing function. So $\arcsin:[-1,1]\to[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ is also strictly increasing.
$\cos:[0,\pi]\to[-1,1]$ is a strictly decreasing function.So, $\arccos:[-1,1]\to[0,\pi]$ is also strictly decreasing. That's how I obtain the inequalities.